# Google Maps iOS Disable Rotation & Tilt

Tags: ios, google-maps, rotation

Trying to disable rotation and tilt on my map view but keep zoom and scrolling.. I have tried the following code but the zoom enabled and scroll enabled cause a error as it says the property is not part of the map view.

```
  self.mapView.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
  self.mapView.zoomEnabled = YES;
  self.mapView.scrollEnabled = YES;
```

Thanks,

Curtis

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I had a few replies to this but managed to solve it myself. There is such a thing called GMSUI Settings which you need to call using the following code..

```
self.mapView.settings.rotateGestures = NO;
self.mapView.settings.tiltGestures = NO;
```

Hope this solved things for others

Answer (score 0):

Xcode 14.2
Swift 5.7

whatever your map-view name is would be what you start with. In my case I named it mapView.

mapView.settings.rotateGestures = false
mapView.settings.tiltGestures = false

Answer (score -1):

Unless you specifically need google maps over Apple maps I would recommend using MKMapView

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKMapView_Class/MKMapView/MKMapView.html

The following properties are defined

```
zoomEnabled
scrollEnabled
pitchEnabled
rotateEnabled
```

pitch would be the tilt you were looking for.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKMapView_Class/MKMapView/MKMapView.html        Apple maps is used in iOS 6.0 and later as per Apple's documentation. Are you using iOS 5? If you aren't, are you sure you aren't using Google's API?

Comment: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/reference/index

If you checkout the documentation from google on their API all of the classes are started with GMS meaning "Google Map Service" while MKMaps is Apple's Api meaning "Map Kit Maps". It loos like you are trying to use Apples map view with Googles API. 

MKMaps between iOS 5 and 6, that was done without changing their Api.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/reference/interface_g_m_s_map_view

The above link is the api reference for GMSMapView which might help you.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/start?hl=ja

The above like contains a tutorial on google maps in iOS.

In Googles documentation it doesn't appear that all of those functions exist.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/reference/interface_g_m_s_u_i_settings it looks like you need to use this class to set the user interface settings